# How install freepascal + lazarus in open solaris?

Tags: installation, freepascal, opensolaris

I try to install fpc on open solaris doing this:

```
svn checkout http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/branches/fixes_2_4 fpcfixes2_4

cd fpcfixes2_4
gmake clean all install INSTALL_PREFIX=~
```

As described here: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Getting_Lazarus#Building_and_installing_Free_Pascal_in_UNIXe

However I get this error:

```
gmake: -iVSPTPSOTO: Command not found
gmake: -iSP: Command not found
gmake: -iTP: Command not found
gmake: -iSO: Command not found
gmake: -iTO: Command not found
/usr/xpg4/bin/rm -f build-stamp.*
/usr/xpg4/bin/rm -f base.build-stamp.*
gmake compiler_cycle RELEASE=1
gmake[1]: -iVSPTPSOTO: Command not found
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/jill/basura/fpcfixes2_4'
gmake[1]: -iSP: Command not found
gmake[1]: -iTP: Command not found
gmake[1]: -iSO: Command not found
gmake[1]: -iTO: Command not found
```

Comment: If you don't mind cross compiling from Linux or Windows, then CodeTyphon might be an easy intermediate solution for Solaris development. http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Free Pascal Compiler is written on Free Pascal. This means that you need an existing Free Pascal Compiler binary to compile a new version.

While at least Solaris/SPARC and Solaris/i386 are supported in svn trunk (I'm not sure about x86_64), we currently don't offer any binaries because we have no real maintainers for these platforms. Also, I think that only Solaris/SPARC is supported in the fixes branch.

Since there is no binary bootstrap compiler available for Solaris, you'd have to cross-compile the initial version on another platform. See http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf for more information.